# Git rebasing interactive not squashing when fast forward available

Tags: git

I have a branch from master with three changes and want to rebase it back on to master. For example:

```
$git checkout master
$git branch dev && git checkout dev
$<do 3 commits>
$git checkout master
$git rebase dev -i
```

Normally -i would give me the 3 commits and allow me to squash. In this case however it is just "noop" and when the rebase completes I see the three commits moved over to master. I guess here though, as the ancestor had not diverged, a fast forward was possible and so this is what happened. But I want to squash the commits.

I tried using --no-ff but it does exactly the same as in my original case (noop + no squashing).

I tried also doing (while on the dev branch)

```
$git rebase -i HEAD~3
$git checkout master
$git rebase dev
```

But this is a pain really and I have to know how many commits to squash for the HEAD~X part.

Footnote:
The reason this is important to me is that it is this squashed changeset that will be reviewed in gerrit. If they are separate, it makes reviewing impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you're doing some of the things in your question, e.g. don't you really mean `$git branch dev && git checkout dev` before you do the commits?  With your version you're just creating them on `master` anyway.  (Incidentally, if I'm right, you can do `git checkout -b dev` as a shortcut.)

The reason you just get a noop is that `git rebase` tries to reapply all the commits in the *current* branch that aren't in the branch that you supply as the `<upstream>` argument.  So, when you do `git rebase -i dev` while on `master`, there are no commits in `master` that aren't on `dev`.  Essentially, you want to do it the other way round.  I would do the following:

```
git checkout dev
git rebase -i master
[... change to 'squash' all but the first of the actions ...]
```

Then your dev branch will just have one squashed commit and you can merge that into master if you like.

Alternatively, you could use `git merge --squash`:

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash dev
git commit -m "The changes from dev squashed into one commit"
```

Then `master` will have a single new commit, which represents the result of merging `dev` into master squashed into one commit, and that new commit will only have one parent, rather than being a merge commit.

Comment: The key here is really using `master` as the base for the rebase, rather than some specifically-named commit. Even if master is too far back, you know that everything you could possibly want to squash is since then. (Also, doesn't `merge --squash` still auto-commit?)

Comment: @Jefromi: in all the versions of git I've used recently, `git merge --squash` just stages the changes.  Did that not used to be the case?

Comment: The documentation added in the commit that introduced `git merge --squash` (7d0c68871a8) also says "do not actually make a commit".

Comment: Never mind then! It does perhaps create a template message? That might be what I was thinking of.

Comment: Yep, you are correct, there was a typo in the checkout. Corrected now. Cheers for the checkout -b tip - new to git!